# Selecting Rows in a Column Contingent on Two Variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a data set that contains multiple observations for each prescription a patient is taking, with many different patients. Patients typically take one of several drugs, which are indicated as their own binary variables, `Drug1`, `Drug2` and so on.

I am attempting to pull out only the individuals that have switched from one drug to the other, i.e, have a `1` in `Drug1` column and `Drug2`, but these occur in different rows.

I have attempted to use `newdata <- mydata[which(Drug1 == 1 & Drug2 == 1),]` however, this assumes that the `1`'s are in the same row, which they are not.

Is there a way to select the patients that have received both drugs, but the indicator variables are in different rows?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a solution to what you are asking using dplyr.

```
data <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), each = 2),
               drug1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
               drug2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
               )
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(both_drugs = ifelse(any(drug1 == 1)  & any(drug2 == 1), 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(both_drugs == 1)
```

Comment: No need to mutate, can just `filter(any(yada) && any(bada))`

Comment: I agree, the mutate can be useful to verify the result gives what you want.

Comment: This finds the individuals who have taken both drugs, but the question is for individuals who have taken one drug and then switched to another. It might not count if they take both drugs at the same time.

Comment: Thank you both! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable for each drug that indicates whether or not it was the only drug taken at that time by that individual.

```
data <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), each = 3),
                   drug1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                   drug2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))

library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(drug1only = ifelse(drug1==1 & drug2==0, 1, 0),
         drug2only = ifelse(drug2==1 & drug1==0, 1, 0)) %>%
  summarise(
    drug_switch = ifelse(max(drug1only)+max(drug2only)==2,1,0))
```

Comment: It works differently from what Brandon LeBeau posted. If you want individuals who took both drugs, whether they took them at the same time or not, then Brandon's answer seems correct. My answer gets you the individuals who took both drugs, but only if they took them at different times.